# zero-to-many relationship efcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created two classes language and country using the format:

```
public class Country{
public string Id{get; set;}
public string CountryName {get; set;}
public ICollection<Language> Languages {get; set;}
}
public class Language{
public string Id{get; set;}
public string LanguageName{get; set;}
}
```

I have created the context and the database, but I noticed that the language table shows its columns as:

Id

LanguageName

CountryId

which indicates a one-to-many relationship, but this isn't what I want(countryId shouldn't be in the Language table)
Is it possible to have a "zero-to-many" relationship in this format?

Comment: In the current model a Country can have zero-to-many Languages, and each Language belongs to exactly one Country.  Do you want many-to-many? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: This is an example of many to many relationship because a launguage e.g English is spoken by many countries

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the zero-to-many relationship works well from the Country model, I was only surprised when I checked the db created and I saw movieId in it. I think i would go with many-to-many relationship then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order EF could recognize many-to-many relations, add public virtual ICollection Countries {get; set;} property to Language class and it should be enough

```
public class Country
{
public string Id{get; set;}
public string CountryName {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<CountryLanguage> CountryLanguages {get; set;}
}

public class Language
{
public string Id{get; set;}
public string LanguageName{get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<CountryLanguage> CountryLanguages {get; set;}
}
```

I usually recommend to add the third table. But if you are using Net5+ it is optional.

```
public class CountryLanguage
{
public string CountryId{get; set;}
public string LanguageId{get; set;}
public virtual Country Country {get; set;}
public virtual Language Language {get; set;}
}
```

Also, if you are using Net5+ you don't  need to add any relations, Ef will do it for you. But if you are using older version let us know.

Comment: Hi Serge, I actually went this route and I kept getting a cyclic error whenever I tried adding to the Country table. How do I go about this?
I'm using .net 5

Comment: Can you please show  the code that you are using when trying to add?

Comment: `country.Id = await randomizer.GenerateGuid();

                await context.Countries.AddAsync(country);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
`

that's what i use

Comment: Dont use AddAsync. Try this  var id= await randomizer.GenerateGuid();  var country= new Country { Id=id, CountryName="name" }; context.Countries.Add(country); await context.SaveChangesAsync(); and let me know if it works

Comment: I just tried that, I'm getting a different error now:
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Languages'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Languages'. The duplicate key value is (10).

it seems efcore is trying to add a new instance of the Language to the Language table, even tho it already exists.

Comment: What languages has to to with this country object? CountryLanguage is completely different table and should be empty for the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235317/discussion-between-samuel-olagesin-and-serge).